# How can I create a function parameter that expects a hashtable?

Tags: .net, powershell, hashtable

I want to create a function that expects a hashtable.

How can I achieve this?

```
function ([string]foo, [#what to write here]myHAshTable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this?

```
function ([string]$foo, [hashtable]$myHAshTable)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to specify type (i.e. [hashtable] - you can just pass the variable provided you're referencing the hash correctly within your function.  For example, passing the hashtable parameter $hash:

```
 foreach ($key in $hash.Keys){
         Write-Host $hash[$key]
     }
```